# How to temporarly disable the app from be visible in Google Play

Tags: publish, google-play-console

I simply want my production App to be invisible for users, so the users can't install the app for some hours. After some hours I would like the app to be visible again.

I searched in the new GUI of Google Play Console and found the following :

```
 App Availability
Your app is currently available on the Play Store.
To remove your app from the Play Store, select Unpublish.
```

In the past it was so easy to disable the app temporarly and it was so intuitiv, so I would not have to ask this here.
But now I am not sure how to unpublish the app temporarly and do not dare to press the button, because I fear the app and all statistics (ratings ) are gone forever.

How to TEMPORARLY unpublish an app ? (for some hours)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Unpublish" does exactly what the old UI did. It will not be visible to old users (but will be visible to existing users). All the reviews and stats will still be present. When you want it visible again, just publish again as before.

Out of curiousity, why do you want to do this?

Comment: Yes sounds stupid :-). But my app also is depending on content stored on a server (no google dependency), which will be downloaded from the app. And there is a moment where I have to switch the content (takes some minutes) and the version at the same time, which is not possible. So the best is to just stop the app, switching the content and switch on the app. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Thanks for explaining!